# Solr5.4 indexing using DataImportHandler(joins)

Tags: join, solr, dataimporthandler

I am using `Solr 5.4`. Working on indexing entities using `Data Import Handler` which are having inner joins and left joins as below.

Does `solr5.4` supports inner joins and left joins?

I am having a query which has relationship between 7 tables. I am doing inner joins for few and left joins for few tables.

below is my query declared in `data-config.xml` file.

```
SELECT rel.*,
               PRODUCT_SRC_SYS.PRODUCT_SRC_NME AS sourceName
          FROM (SELECT REF.*,
                       PRODUCT_RLSP.OBJ_ID AS relObjId                
                  FROM (SELECT prdct.*,
                               PRODUCT_CATEGORY.OBJ_ID AS refObjId
                               PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAPG.category_mapng_Name
                                  AS refCategoryMapngName,
                               PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIFE_CYL.LIFE_CYL_STAT_TYP
                                  AS refStatus
                          FROM (SELECT PRODUCT.RGSTRY_ID
                                          AS id
                                       PRODUCT.OBJ_ID
                                          AS obj_id,
                                       PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME 
                                          As product_name,
                                       PRODUCT_STAT.PRODUCT_STAT_TYP
                                          AS status
                                  FROM PRODUCT
                                       LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_STAT
                                          ON PRODUCT.OBJ_ID =
                                                PRODUCT_STAT.OBJ_ID)
                               prdct
                               LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY
                                  ON prdct.product_name =
                                        PRODUCT_CATEGORY.category_name
                               INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAPG
                                  ON PRODUCT_CATEGORY.OBJ_ID =
                                        PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAPG.OBJ_ID
                               INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIFE_CYL
                                  ON PRODUCT_CATEGORY.OBJ_ID =
                                        PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIFE_CYL.OBJ_ID)
                       REF
                       LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_RLSP
                          ON REF.obj_id =
                                PRODUCT_RLSP.OBJ_ID) rel
               LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_SRC_SYS
                  ON rel.obj_id = PRODUCT_SRC_SYS.OBJ_ID
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!